# copy adls gen2 blobs across subscriptions using powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-data-lake-gen2

I'm trying to copy an entire folder/blob from an azure adls gen2 container in one subscription to another subscription.

Before the below code I've already connected to azure and populated hash tables of each subscription detail.

```
Set-AzContext -Subscription $DevDetails.SubscriptionID
$DevStorageAccount = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $DevDetails.ResourceGroup -StorageAccountName $DevDetails.StorageAccount 
$DevContext = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $DevDetails.StorageAccount 
$DevStorageContainer = Get-AzStorageContainer -Name "raw" -Context $DevContext

Set-AzContext -Subscription $PPDetails.SubscriptionID
$PPStorageAccount = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $PPDetails.ResourceGroup -StorageAccountName $PPDetails.StorageAccount 
$PPContext = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $PPDetails.StorageAccount 
$PPStorageContainer = Get-AzStorageContainer -Name "raw" -Context $PPContext

Set-AzContext -Subscription $ProdDetails.SubscriptionID
$PStorageAccount = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $ProdDetails.ResourceGroup -StorageAccountName $ProdDetails.StorageAccount 
$PContext = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $ProdDetails.StorageAccount 
$PStorageContainer = Get-AzStorageContainer -Name "raw" -Context $PContext
```

I've got the variables for context for all 3 environments.

In the prod storagecontainer raw we have a gen 2 folder in a hierarchical namespace. (Folder1/Folder2/Folder3)

I would like to copy the folder and all contents from prod back to dev.  Trying this command.

```
Start-AzStorageBlobCopy -DestContainer $DevStorageContainer.Name -Context $PContext -SrcBlob "Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/" -SrcContainer $PStorageContainer.Name -DestContext $DevContext
```

I get the error

```
Status: 403 (This request is not authorized to perform this operation.)
ErrorCode: CannotVerifyCopySource
```

I've also tried this.

```
$prodblob = Get-AzStorageBlob -Context $PContext -Container $PStorageContainer.Name -Blob "Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/"
$prodblob | Start-AzStorageBlobCopy -DestContainer $DevStorageContainer.Name -Context $DevContext
```

which gives the same error.

I'm able to copy it manually across using azure storage explorer and also able to do it using azcopy so it doesn't seem to be a permission issue.

Is this just not compatible with adls gen2 and I'm going about it completely wrong or is there something simple I'm missing?

Comment: For some reason you can't use `azcopy` or why did you want to use `Start-AzStorageBlobCopy`?

Comment: @KKI mainly because I'm better in powershell and using the command line makes it harder to automatically handle errors.  For some reason AZcopy has been repeatedly erroring.  I can rerun the command until it succeeds but.

Comment: Hi there, have you got a chance to check the answer below? May I know if it can address your concern？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blob means files in this context.

I think your code can actually work if you set the `-DestBlob`.

**EDIT**: You can't copy a whole folder with the `Start-AzStorageBlobCopy`.

---

This is a sample code that retrieves all containers from storage account 1, and then creates the non-existing ones on storage account 2.

It then queries all files within the current container and copies them from SA1 to SA2.

**Attention!** the `-Force` option is included, so overwriting is possible.
If you want to avoid this, just delete it.

```
#connect
Connect-AzAccount

#get all relevant information from the source
Set-AzContext -Subscription "SUB1"
$SourceResourceGroup = "SUB1_RG"
$SourceStorageAccount = "SUB1_SA"
$SourceStorageKey = (Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $SourceResourceGroup -Name $SourceStorageAccount)[0].Value
$SourceStorageContext = New-AZStorageContext -StorageAccountName $SourceStorageAccount -StorageAccountKey $SourceStorageKey

#get all relevant information from the destination
Set-AzContext -Subscription "SUB2"
$DestResourceGroup = "SUB2_RG"
$DestStorageAccount = "SUB2_SA"
$DestStorageKey = (Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $DestResourceGroup -Name $DestStorageAccount)[0].Value
$DestStorageContext = New-AZStorageContext -StorageAccountName $DestStorageAccount -StorageAccountKey $DestStorageKey

#get all container from the source
$Containers = Get-AZStorageContainer -Context $SourceStorageContext

#do something with all container
foreach ($Container in $Containers) {
    $ContainerName = $Container.Name
    #Generate new container if does not exist
    if (!((Get-AZStorageContainer -Context $DestStorageContext) | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $ContainerName })) {   
        Write-Output "Creating new container $ContainerName"
        New-AZStorageContainer -Name $ContainerName -Permission Off -Context $DestStorageContext -ErrorAction Stop
    }

    #get all file
    $Blobs = Get-AZStorageBlob -Context $SourceStorageContext -Container $ContainerName

    #Copy all file with overwrite! just delete the "-Force" if you don't want to overwrite your existing files
    foreach ($Blob in $Blobs) {
        $BlobName = $Blob.Name
        Write-Output "Copying $BlobName from $ContainerName"
        Start-AzStorageBlobCopy -Context $SourceStorageContext -SrcContainer $ContainerName -SrcBlob $BlobName -DestContext $DestStorageContext -DestContainer $ContainerName -DestBlob $BlobName -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }
}
```

If it was helpful please upvote it or accept the answer.

Comment: the code doesn't quite do what I wanted to but I'm accepting for the comment "You can't copy a whole folder with the Start-AzStorageBlobCopy"

Comment: Thank you and sorry, I must have misunderstood something.
What is your exact request?
Isn't it to copy data from the DEV blob to the PROD blob?
The script will copy everything, but with a little fine tuning you can make it more granular. Something like "if" or any filter etc.

Comment: Nothing wrong with what you've done @KKI it fits the scenario but it doesn't have the throughput that AZcopy does.  I basically wanted to replicate the azcopy sync command in powershell as azcopy isn't as easy to handle errors in.  I appreciate the help.